# How do I properly use ImageMagick.NET in ASPNET Core running on Linux Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: asp.net-core, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I am attempting to create an ASPNET Core application where I want to show thumbnail images.  I have elected to use the ImageMagick.NET framework as it has a nuget package for dotnet core.  When developing on a Windows computer using Visual Studio 2015 the thumbnail images work fine.  I now attempt to publish to a Linux server - Ubuntu 16.04.  The application runs and shows output to the console.  When I attempt to use the ImageMagick objects I receive an error...

```
An unhandled exception has occurred: Unable to load DLL 'Magick.NET-Q16-x64.Native.dll': The specified module could not be found.
```

Searches on my Linux computer reveal this file is nowhere on the filesystem.  I have this file on my windows development system, so I copied it to my Linux server where my ASPNET Core .dll file resides, but still I get this error.

I now wonder if I must install some ImageMagick runtime files on my Linux server, but I am not sure.

What is the proper way to use ImageMagick with dotnet core considering the development system is Windows and the production system is Linux?

Answer (score 3):

OK - According to the [Magick.NET Website](https://magick.codeplex.com/), this only works for windows, and is not compatible with Linux.

The [ImageMagick Documentation](https://magick.codeplex.com/documentation) clearly states in the .NET Core section...

> Starting with version 7.0.0.0102 support for .NET Core was added. This
>   currently only works on Windows.

Derp!